# Problem using a prop in functional component IT Says TypeError: onClick is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

im having problems trying to use the onclick function as props it sais when i clicked TypeError: onClick is not a function
What can i do!
7 |         <Card

> 8 |             onClick={() => onClick(dish.id)}>
> | ^   9 |

it is my first time using this kind of components

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay,
    CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

    function RenderMenuItem ({dish, onClick}) {
        return (
            <Card
                onClick={() => onClick(dish.id)}>
                <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                <CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                </CardImgOverlay>
            </Card>
        );
    }

    const Menu = (props) => {

        const menu = props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1"  key={dish.id}>
                    <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} onClick={props.onClick} />
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {menu}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default Menu;
```

Comment: It may be that `onClick` is not a function when passed to `Menu`. How are you calling `Menu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have default props to avoid run time errors.

```
const Menu = (props) => {
  const menu = props.dishes.map((dish) => {
    return (
      <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1" key={dish.id}>
        <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} onClick={props.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">{menu}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

Menu.defaultProps = {
  dishes: [],
  onClick: () => {},
};
```

You must now use `Menu` component by providing valid function. For example `<Menu onClick={dishId => {/* Logic /*}}/>`

Comment: If your program is missing a click handler, that seems like something I'd want to see an error about. A default prop with a function that does nothing is more confusing to track down. At the very least it should throw an error to the console saying that the default prop is being used so that the developer can figure out why.